# HtmlUnit read specific link information inbetween the <a> tags

Tags: parsing, hyperlink, html-parsing, htmlunit

I am connecting to a webpage using HtmlUnit and I want to read the information inbetween the  tags. I will demonstrate using some code. Lets suppose I have the following link:

```
<a href="www.anypage.com"> Hello! </a>
```

I would like to read the `Hello` that's in between, preferably saved into a `String` variable. Here is the code essential for the task

```
// Simulating a Chrome browser
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME); 
loggedIn = webClient.getPage("random-page.com");
HtmlAnchor anchorLink = loggedIn.getAnchorByHref("/private-messages/inbox");
```

Now if I use `anchorLink.toString()` I get `<a href="www.anypage.com">` from the previous example but nothing about the characters inbetween the tags. I have gone through the API and I can't seem to find anything useful. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `getTextContent()` be what you are looking for?